# Time out issue - http-incoming-1 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:59531

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 EI studio 7.0.2 . I created an API & compiled and deployed in studio ( embedded microintegrator server ) .  But before execurting the API i can see a timeout warning log as follows

```
[2020-05-14 13:29:06,291]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-1 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:59531
[2020-05-14 13:29:06,292]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} - Connection time out while writing the response: http-incoming-2 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:59532
```

Can someone please let me know what exactly studio is trying to do? I have just simple passthrough API. I checked my system's proxy settings also. All looks good.

I am unable to understand why its writing a warning log (mentioned above)  without invoking / executing API.